# How do I stop my desktop folders moving when I plug a screen into my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac

Whenever I connect my 24" monitor into my mac I end up with the folders on my desktop moving to the left and then when I take it out I have to re-sort them, does anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: Do you have folders set to sort on your desktop? I know when I have any sort set and I change resolution the icons are resorted to accommodate the new resolution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off sorting by right (command) clicking on the desktop, then selecting "sort" and "none".
   [image: Turn off sorting on OSX desktop]
2. Arrange your icons on the lowest resolution display. If you arrange them on the higher resolution display, they will have to be moved to accomodate the smaller size of your Macbook's screen.